# Elemento Select2 Bloqueado desde la segunda línea agregada dinámicamente

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, laravel-6

Estimad@s por favor, su orientación en el siguiente detalle al agregar filas dinámicas el elemento select2 se bloquea desde la segunda línea y no permite desplegar para realizar la búsqueda de otro item para esa línea(la búsqueda la realizo por ajax, también funciona correctamente, para el ejemplo coloqué elementos option xyz), con el elemento select normal tambien funciona, el resto de elementos funcionan correctamente inclusive los cálculos, por favor agradezco su colaboración, o alguna sugerencia, adjunto el código.
.....................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let row_number = 1;
  $("#add_row").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let new_row_number = row_number - 1;
    $('#product' + row_number).html($('#product' + new_row_number).html()).find('td:first-child');
    $('#products_table').append('<tr id="product' + (row_number + 1) + '"></tr>');
    row_number++;
  });

  $("#delete_row").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (row_number > 1) {
      $("#product" + (row_number - 1)).html('');
      row_number--;
    }
    calc();
  });

  //agregado
  $('#products_table tbody').on('keyup change', function() {
    calc();
  });
  $('#carc_com_iva').on('keyup change', function() {
    calc_total();
  });

});

//agragado
function calc() {
  $('#products_table tbody tr').each(function(i, element) {
    var html = $(this).html();
    if (html != '') {
      var quantities = $(this).find('.quantities').val();
      var price = parseFloat($(this).find('.price').val());
      var descuento = $(this).find('.descuento').val();
      valor_descuento = parseFloat((price / 100 * descuento) * quantities);
      $(this).find('.valor_descuento').val(valor_descuento.toFixed(2));
      $(this).find('.total').val(parseFloat((quantities * price) - valor_descuento).toFixed(2));
      calc_total();
    }
  });
}

function calc_total() {
  total = 0;

  $('.total').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
  $('#carc_com_sub_total').val(total.toFixed(2));
  tax_sum = total / 100 * $('#carc_com_iva').val();
  $('#carc_com_iva_valor').val(tax_sum.toFixed(2));
  $('#carc_com_total').val((tax_sum + total).toFixed(2));
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    carc_com_detalle
  </div>

  <div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-bordered table-striped table-sm" id="products_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>carc_med_descripcion</th>
          <th>carc_mod_precio</th>
          <th>carc_mod_cantidad</th>
          <th>carc_mod_descuento</th>
          <th>carc_mod_descuento_valor</th>
          <th>carc_mod_total_item</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="product0">
          <td style="width: 50%">

            <select name="products[]" class="js-example-basic-single" required>
              <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
              ...
              <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
              <option value="WY">XXXXXXXXXX</option>
              <option value="WY">YYYYYYY</option>
              <option value="WY">ZZZZZ</option>
            </select>

          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='0,00' class="form-control price" step="0.01" min="0.01" required/>
          </td>
          <td width="10%">
            <input type="number" name="quantities[]" class="form-control quantities" value="1" min="1" required/>
          </td>
          <td width="9%">
            <input type="number" name="descuento[]" class="form-control descuento" placeholder="0 %" step="0" min="0" value="0" required/>
          </td>
          <td width="10%">
            <input type="number" name="valor_descuento[]" class="form-control valor_descuento" readonly/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='0,00' class="form-control total" readonly/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="product1"></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">+</button>
        <button id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- agragado  class="row clearfix"  justify-content-end-->
    <div class="row justify-content-end " style="margin-top:20px">
      <div class="pull-right col-md-4">
        <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-bordered table-striped table-sm" id="tab_logic_total">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">carc_com_sub_total</th>
              <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='carc_com_sub_total' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" id="carc_com_sub_total" readonly /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">carc_com_iva</th>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mb-sm-0">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="carc_com_iva" placeholder="0" name="carc_com_iva" value="12" readonly>
                  <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">carc_com_iva_valor</th>
              <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='carc_com_iva_valor' id="carc_com_iva_valor" placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" readonly /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">{{ trans('cruds.order.fields.carc_com_total')}}</th>
              <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='carc_com_total' id="carc_com_total" placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" readonly /></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- agragado -->
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="{{save}}">
</div>
</form>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que destruir y volver a inicializar los select2 asi:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let row_number = 1;
  $("#add_row").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2('destroy');
    let new_row_number = row_number - 1;
    $('#product' + row_number).html($('#product' + new_row_number).html()).find('td:first-child');
    $('#products_table').append('<tr id="product' + (row_number + 1) + '"></tr>');
    row_number++;
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
  });

  $("#delete_row").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (row_number > 1) {
      $("#product" + (row_number - 1)).html('');
      row_number--;
    }
    calc();
  });

  //agregado
  $('#products_table tbody').on('keyup change', function() {
    calc();
  });
  $('#carc_com_iva').on('keyup change', function() {
    calc_total();
  });

});

//agragado
function calc() {
  $('#products_table tbody tr').each(function(i, element) {
    var html = $(this).html();
    if (html != '') {
      var quantities = $(this).find('.quantities').val();
      var price = parseFloat($(this).find('.price').val());
      var descuento = $(this).find('.descuento').val();
      valor_descuento = parseFloat((price / 100 * descuento) * quantities);
      $(this).find('.valor_descuento').val(valor_descuento.toFixed(2));
      $(this).find('.total').val(parseFloat((quantities * price) - valor_descuento).toFixed(2));
      calc_total();
    }
  });
}

function calc_total() {
  total = 0;

  $('.total').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
  $('#carc_com_sub_total').val(total.toFixed(2));
  tax_sum = total / 100 * $('#carc_com_iva').val();
  $('#carc_com_iva_valor').val(tax_sum.toFixed(2));
  $('#carc_com_total').val((tax_sum + total).toFixed(2));
}


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    carc_com_detalle
  </div>

  <div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-bordered table-striped table-sm" id="products_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>carc_med_descripcion</th>
          <th>carc_mod_precio</th>
          <th>carc_mod_cantidad</th>
          <th>carc_mod_descuento</th>
          <th>carc_mod_descuento_valor</th>
          <th>carc_mod_total_item</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="product0">
          <td style="width: 50%">

            <select name="products[]" class="js-example-basic-single" required>
              <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
              ...
              <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
              <option value="WY">XXXXXXXXXX</option>
              <option value="WY">YYYYYYY</option>
              <option value="WY">ZZZZZ</option>
            </select>

          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name='price[]' placeholder='0,00' class="form-control price" step="0.01" min="0.01" required/>
          </td>
          <td width="10%">
            <input type="number" name="quantities[]" class="form-control quantities" value="1" min="1" required/>
          </td>
          <td width="9%">
            <input type="number" name="descuento[]" class="form-control descuento" placeholder="0 %" step="0" min="0" value="0" required/>
          </td>
          <td width="10%">
            <input type="number" name="valor_descuento[]" class="form-control valor_descuento" readonly/>
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="number" name='total[]' placeholder='0,00' class="form-control total" readonly/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="product1"></tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button id="add_row" class="btn btn-primary pull-left">+</button>
        <button id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-danger">-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- agragado  class="row clearfix"  justify-content-end-->
    <div class="row justify-content-end " style="margin-top:20px">
      <div class="pull-right col-md-4">
        <table class="table table-responsive-sm table-bordered table-striped table-sm" id="tab_logic_total">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">carc_com_sub_total</th>
              <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='carc_com_sub_total' placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" id="carc_com_sub_total" readonly /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">carc_com_iva</th>
              <td class="text-center">
                <div class="input-group mb-2 mb-sm-0">
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" id="carc_com_iva" placeholder="0" name="carc_com_iva" value="12" readonly>
                  <div class="input-group-addon">%</div>
                </div>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">carc_com_iva_valor</th>
              <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='carc_com_iva_valor' id="carc_com_iva_valor" placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" readonly /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th class="text-center">{{ trans('cruds.order.fields.carc_com_total')}}</th>
              <td class="text-center"><input type="number" name='carc_com_total' id="carc_com_total" placeholder='0.00' class="form-control" readonly /></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- agragado -->
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="{{save}}">
</div>
</form>


</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto!!! funciona correctamente con las líneas agregadas por @alanfcm ($('.js-example-basic-single').select2('destroy');) y ($('.js-example-basic-single').select2(); gracias por el aporte!!!